# Adding swig2.0 to usr/bin/ in order to run CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, swig

I'm trying to run CMake for my program, but I keep getting errors that all point towards me not having the desired version of swig in my `usr/bin` directory.

Here are the errors I get when I run:

```
home/program/build_program/Debug$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

> CMake Error at
>   /home/my_name/tools/cmake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindSWIG.cmake:39
>   (message):
>   Command "/usr/bin/swig2.0 -swiglib" failed with output:
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMakeLists.txt:245 (FIND_PACKAGE)
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:246 (INCLUDE):
>   INCLUDE called with wrong number of arguments.  include() only takes one file.
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:265 (SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY):
>   Unknown CMake command "SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY".
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
>   See also "/home/program/build_program/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

This is what I see in `usr/bin`:

```
usr/bin$ ls | grep swig
ccache-swig
ccache-swig3.0
swig
swig3.0
```

And these are lines 245, 246, and 265 in my CMakeLists.txt:

> (245) FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
>
> (246) INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
>
> (265) SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY(pymcell 
>       TYPE SHARED 
>       LANGUAGE python
>       SOURCES src/pymcell.i ${SOURCE_FILES}  ${BISON_dynGeomParser_OUTPUTS} ${FLEX_dynGeomScanner_OUTPUTS}
>     )

**I think the solution here is to get swig2.0 in `usr/bin`, but I'm not sure how to do that.**

*What I've tried:*

I've installed swig2.0.12, but there's no file called "swig2.0", and even if there was, I'm not sure how to properly move that into `usr/bin`.

I'm a bit of a noob, so I'm hoping this isn't too silly of a question.

I'm using Debian 9 and CMake 3.15.4.

Comment: You should try setting the CMake variable `set(SWIG_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/swig3.0)` to hint to CMake where to find SWIG before calling `FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG ...)`. As is often the case with CMake, after making this change, it is probably best to clear your CMake cache and run CMake from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, solved! In order to not mess with my colleagues' work, I wrote the following: 

if (NOT /usr/bin/swig2.0)
  set(SWIG_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/swig)
endif()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer:*

The [FindSWIG](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindSWIG.html) module uses the `SWIG_EXECUTABLE` variable as a hint to the location/version of SWIG to use. When a SWIG executable is found, the version is obtained, and *cached* by CMake. Therefore, subsequent uses of CMake will likely expect the **same** version of SWIG.

If using CMake with multiple versions of SWIG, or updating the SWIG path and/or version, you can set this `SWIG_EXECUTABLE` variable to tell CMake where to look.

```
set(SWIG_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/swig3.0)
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
```

When updating the SWIG version or location on your machine, you want to clear any **cached** SWIG variables within CMake so the latest (or correct) version can be found. Do this by clearing the CMake cache, or deleting the CMakeCache.txt file, and re-running CMake.